# Psychologist with different language and culture

Tags: social-psychology, language

Is it better to find a psychologist who is from the same culture, same language, same country .., so he/she will easily understand the problems we'll be speaking about ?

I'm Algerian, living in France, I speak French well, should I find an Algerian psychologist ?

Is it the right place to ask this question ??

Comment: Of course it is better. You can chat and talk in your native language, which will only make the connection stronger. Your problems will easier come forth like this and they are easily solved as a consequence. Unless the culture you are from is one that frowns upon psychology, but in that case there wouldn't be psychiaters in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Normally speaking, this would be deemed a personal advice question and such questions are off-topic, but it is a common question asked within therapy.

I cannot provide sources of information regarding who specifically to see as that is very personal and my advice regarding that could be incorrect for you personally.

What I can tell you is that there are many people from different backgrounds who are very aware of the different cultures around them. If you are Muslim for example, whether you need to see a Muslim therapist is down to who is available in your area and whether that is exactly what you need.

In order for the right person to be chosen, I recommend looking at who you would trust to speak about your issues. **If it is important**, are they aware of the culture you were brought up in and what that entails?

Whether you see a therapist from your culture or not, you may find your first choice is not quite right for you. That is unfortunately common but doesn't mean they were not qualified for the task. It can just be a matter of rapport. You either click with each other or you don't.

Only you can answer this question really and I wish you luck.